# How to create a staked bar chart to show hourly data with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, charts, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an API loading into a power query that gives me hourly weather data over a 15-day period. I've added `=IF(AND([@Precipitation]=0,[@[Wind Speed]]<=10,[@Temperature]>=3),0,1)` formula to give me a True/False result as either 0 or 1. (Forecast Data) I then use this result to perform conditional formatting on these cells.

I'm trying to insert this data into a stacked bar chart to show the date along the x-axis and the time up the y-axis, with the forecast data forming the staked bar with different colours.

Is this possible? Can you help? I've added some images below to help explain what I mean.

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDytu.jpg)
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3xlb.jpg)

Comment: It would be easier to accomplish in a range of cells in a worksheet with times on the left and date as column headers, with each cell referencing the corresponding original data and having conditional formatting to change the color-- if you set both text and background to the same color in the conditional format, it would have the appearance you want. I don't know how to accomplish that in an Excel chart.

Comment: Yes, thanks Chris. I currently have a chart that works in that way. Just wondered if my suggestion was a possibility.